# How to mimic a full outer join using mysql views?

Tags: mysql, view

I have all kinds of views in mysql with employee data.  I have tried to use methods like this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384298/why-does-mysql-report-a-syntax-error-on-full-outer-join but they simply don't work for views.

I end up getting more of a LEFT JOIN as a result.  Is there a way to merge two views without including duplicates in mysql - I am currently using a 4 view process to duplicate this.

Comment: Full joining 2 views is no different than full joining 2 tables. Shows us what you tried.

Comment: @ypercube - I did exactly what was in the link.  I got all of the entries that weren't matches.   I have tried unions and group bys but I have to run them over several views to get them to work.  I can get it working but not in one view statement.  I want to know how I can take viewA and add viewB (and ViewC and ViewD...) where there are no duplicate ids.

Comment: Did you try the answer there with 3 views/tables? I think that answer is wrong when it comes to 3+ tables. Edit the question and add the `SHOW CREATE VIEW viewname;` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simulation of `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
( SELECT ... FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON ... ) -- Intersection, plus rest of b
UNION ALL  -- There will be no overlap; ALL is faster
( SELECT ... FROM b LEFT JOIN a ON ... WHERE a.id IS NULL ) -- Just rest of a
```

(The link given is less efficient because it gets the Intersection twice, then dedups by doing `UNION DISTINCT`.)

If you need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` between more than 2 tables, then it gets messier.  (But you did not ask for that.)